# Taking a matrix and retrieving both the diagonals keeping the dimensions of the original matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

Given the matrix `A = magic(5)` you get:

```
A =  17    24     1     8    15
     23     5     7    14    16
     4      6    13    20    22
     10    12    19    21     3
     11    18    25     2     9
```

I want to use commands such as `rot90`, `diag`, `triu`, `tril` and matrices `sum` to get the matrix:

```
A =  17    0     0     0     15
     0     5     0     14    0
     0     0     13    0     0
     0     12    0     21    0
     11    0     0     0     9
```

Please, if you can't think of a way to solve this without the commands I wrote, it's OK to do it your own way.

Comment: Just a tip: whenever you have code, write it/copy from your editor and later select all of it and click on the brackets (aka code block) so it is rendered nicely

Comment: Just changed the title and did as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`eye`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eye.html) function for indexing

```
>> A(~eye(size(A)) & ~flipud(eye(size(A))))=0
A =
    17     0     0     0    15
     0     5     0    14     0
     0     0    13     0     0
     0    12     0    21     0
    11     0     0     0     9
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) to access the diagonals:

```
n = size(A,1);
B = zeros(n);
B( 1:(n+1):end ) = A( 1:(n+1):end ); %// main diagonal
B( n:(n-1):(end-n+1) ) = A( n:(n-1):(end-n+1) )
```

And you get

```
B =
17     0     0     0    15
 0     5     0    14     0
 0     0    13     0     0
 0    12     0    21     0
11     0     0     0     9
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is:

```
mDiag   = diag(diag(A));
aDiag   = rot90(diag(diag(rot90(A))))';
overlap = A.*((diag(diag(A)) ~= 0) & (rot90(diag(diag(rot90(A)))) ~= 0));

solution = mDiag + aDiag - overlap
```

And than:

```
solution =
17     0     0     0    15
 0     5     0    14     0
 0     0    13     0     0
 0    12     0    21     0
11     0     0     0     9
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `bsxfun`

```
out = A.*bsxfun(@(x,y) x == y | x+y == size(A,1)+1,(1:size(A,1)).',1:size(A,1))    %//'
```